# Django saving nested formsets that are related to each other column cannot be null error

Tags: django, django-forms

There are two nested formsets and they are related to each other. When I increase the extra field in the second formset, I get the error column cannot be null. I have no problem saving both forms as one.

Here is my error :

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glcmK.png)

Here is my forms :

```
class UserTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserTask
        fields = ['user_id','task_types_id','store_house_id','description']


class TaskSourcesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskSources
        fields = ['product_id', 'product_amount']




TaskSourcesFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    TaskSources,
    fields=('product_id', 'product_amount',),
    extra=2,
)    



UserTaskFormFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    UserTask,
    fields=('user_id','task_types_id','store_house_id','description',),
    extra=1,
)
```

here is my views :

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def addUserTask(request):

    user_task_form = UserTaskFormFormSet(queryset=UserTask.objects.none(),initial=[{'user_id': request.user}])
    formset = TaskSourcesFormSet(queryset=TaskSources.objects.none())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_task_form = UserTaskFormFormSet(request.POST)
        formset = TaskSourcesFormSet(request.POST)
        
        if user_task_form.is_valid():
            for form in user_task_form:
                user_task = form.save(commit=False)
                user_task.author = request.user
                user_task.save()
            
            if formset.is_valid():
                for form_data in formset:
                    task_sources = form_data.save(commit=False)
                    task_sources.user_task_id = UserTask(id = user_task.id)
                    task_sources.save()
                   
            messages.success(request,"Task added successfully!")
        return redirect(".")

    context = {
        "user_task_form" : user_task_form,
        "formset" : formset,
    }

    return render(request,"user/addtask.html",context)
```

How to save two model formsets together(relates to each other) in one view? what is the wrong part when i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from empty fields in your formsets forms.  You can avoid empty forms with:

```
        for form in user_task_form:
            if form.has_changed():
               user_task = form.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Your answer worked when I made the extra field manually. Before using the usertask form as an fromset, I was able to add multiple tasksources dynamically. Now when I dynamically say "add new product" it only saves the first form. 
what could be the reason for this? By the way, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: When you dynamically add new forms,  are you using the same form field names each time eg `<input name='field_1'>`? Check how the fields names change in a formset with multiple forms by default and try and emulate that

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that, by your indentation, you are looping through all of `user_task_form` and only when finished looping through `formset`. This means every `task_sources` will have the same `user_task_id`, the last one used in the previous loop.

Comment: I want each `task_sources` to have the same user task id. Because I may need to add multiple `task_sources` to one user task. About id's first form select id is `select2-id_form-0-product_id-container`and id of the second dynamically added `select2-id_form-1-product_id-container`. I created a new question to make it clearer, can you please check it?  [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635783/django-nested-model-formsets-only-save-the-first-form)

Comment: I noticed that both forms have a `{{management_form}}` tag. (`{{ user_task_form.management_form }}` and  `{{ formset.management_form }}` ) and both have fields with the same name. When I manually increase the extra area, it increases the total form area of ​​the second `{{management_form}}` form. But when I increase it dynamically, it increases the total form area of ​​the first `{{management_form}}`  form. 
how can i fix this?

Comment: I solved problem added `prefix` each form and edit js thanks.